# Very basic stuff: having trouble with a program simulating a slot machine- enums and arrays

Tags: java, arrays, enums

So my professor gave out an assignment in which we have to create an operating slot machine program. The machine has 3 reels, which themselves consist of 6 six symbols stored in an enum:

```
public enum Symbol 
{   
    SEVEN(12,"images/seven.jpg"),
    WATERMELON(10,"images/watermelon.jpg"),
    ORANGE(8,"images/orange.jpg"),
    PLUM(6,"images/plum.jpg"),
    LEMON(4,"images/lemon.jpg"),
    CHERRY(2,"images/cherry.jpg");
}
```

We're supposed to use these symbols to create a "reel" object. My problem is centered around populating this reel (which is really just a Symbol[] array) with the symbols in the order requested by the professor.

He asked us to use the Random class to populate the reel using 10 as the seed number. Here's what I have so far:

```
//Creating an unrandomized reel array, which contains the symbols in the exact order as they appear in the enum
private Symbol[] unrandomizedReel = new Symbol[]{Symbol.SEVEN, Symbol.WATERMELON, Symbol.ORANGE, Symbol.PLUM, Symbol.LEMON, Symbol.CHERRY};

//Declares local Symbol array
Symbol[] randomizedReel = new Symbol[6];

//Keeps track of the position in the unradomized reel array
int unrandomizedReelIndex = 0;

//Creates a Random object which will be used to generate values based
//on the seed. **seed == 10**
Random randNum = new Random(seed);

//Loop will populate the randomized reel
while(unrandomizedReelIndex < 6)
  {
    //This int will hold values ranging from 0-5. Will be used as an index
    //to populate randomized reel
    int rangedRandomNumIndex = randNum.nextInt(6);

    //if the element at the given index in the randomized reel is empty
    if(randomizedReel[rangedRandomNumIndex] == null)
      {
        //A symbol from the unrandomized reel is added to it
        randomizedReel[rangedRandomNumIndex] = unrandomizedReel[unrandomizedReelIndex];

        //The index used to iterate through the unrandomized reel is incremented by 1
        unrandomizedReelIndex++;
      }
  }
```

Running this "shuffling" code, I get the following output:

```
WATERMELON
PLUM
CHERRY
SEVEN
ORANGE
LEMON
```

However, according to my professor, the output should be:

```
ORANGE
PLUM
SEVEN
LEMON
WATERMELON
CHERRY
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is my output different from his, even though we are both using 10 as a seed? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you required to use a specific algorithm to do the shuffling? I'm not seeing anything wrong with your solution, could just be slightly different from your prof's (e.g., the random number could represent the index into the old array rather than the new one, or you could use a random number to swap values some number of times)

Comment: "could just be slightly different from your prof's..." That did the trick. Thanks, Kyle!

Answer (score 1):

```
new Symbol[]{Symbol.SEVEN, Symbol.WATERMELON, Symbol.ORANGE, Symbol.PLUM, Symbol.LEMON, Symbol.CHERRY};
```

can be simplified to

```
Symbol.values()
```

My guess would be that your professor is putting

```
   unrandomizedReel[Random.nextInt(6)]
```

in position 0, then nulling that out that element of `unrandomizedReel`, getting a random number x between 1 and 5 and taking the  x-th non-null value and putting it in position 1, nulling it, then repeating with a number between 1 and 4 and so on.

If you have a reason to believe your professor is using a different algo, then edit your question with that information.

Comment: Thanks for responding, Mike. Unfortunately, my professor told us that we can't use anything other than arrays.